# MongoDB : aggregation framework : $match between fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a test collection with two documents :

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510114b46c1a3a0f6e5dd7aa"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("510114c86c1a3a0f6e5dd7ab"), "a" : 3, "b" : 1 }
```

With aggregation framework, I want to get only the documents where a is greater than b.
$gt get only values in argument not fields...

```
> db.test.aggregate([{"$match":{"$a":{"$gt":"$b"}}}])
{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 } /* don't work*/
```

Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: It seems you made an error in your aggregation query. The field you wish to match should be specified as `a`, not `$a`, i.e. `db.test.aggregate([{"$match":{"a":{"$gt":"$b"}}}])`

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions, that still won't work, MongoDB won't use the value of  the field `b`, it will  use `$b` as the right hand side of the comparison.  This can be tested by executing `db.test.aggregate([{"$match":{"a":{"$eq":"$a"}}}])`.  Zero results will be returned.

Comment: You can use aggregation expression in regular query in 3.6. Something like `db.test.find( {"$expr": {"$gt": ["$a", "$b"]}})` and in aggregation thru `db.test.aggregate( {"$match":{"$expr": {"$gt": ["$a", "$b"]}}})`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Hmm without much testing on my end I will say you can use `$cmp` for this:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cmp/#_S_cmp

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        // All your other fields here
        cmp_value: {$cmp: ['$a', '$b']}
    }},
    {$match: {cmp_value: {$gt: 0}}} 
])
```

There might be a better way but I haven't got a MongoDB installation near me to test.

Comment: May i know how to use above mongdb query with php language. I've used above method not works. Please help on this.

Comment: @shankarmsr With the new driver: `(new \MongoDB\Client())->db->collection->aggregate([['$project' => ['cmp_value' => ['$cmp' => ['$a', '$b']]]], ['$match' => ['cmp_value' => ['$gt' => 0]]]])` or something like that

Comment: Let me check with your answer.Hope it will works fine

Answer (score 13):

### Use the `$expr` operator.

Introduced in version 3.6, `$expr` can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document.

**Compare Two Fields from A Single Document** (example taken directly from [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#compare-two-fields-from-a-single-document)):

Consider an monthlyBudget collection with the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "category" : "food", "budget": 400, "spent": 450 }
{ "_id" : 2, "category" : "drinks", "budget": 100, "spent": 150 }
{ "_id" : 3, "category" : "clothes", "budget": 100, "spent": 50 }
{ "_id" : 4, "category" : "misc", "budget": 500, "spent": 300 }
{ "_id" : 5, "category" : "travel", "budget": 200, "spent": 650 }
```

The following operation uses `$expr` to find documents where the spent amount exceeds the budget:

```
db.monthlyBudget.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$spent" , "$budget" ] } } )
```

The operation returns the following results:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "category" : "food", "budget" : 400, "spent" : 450 }
{ "_id" : 2, "category" : "drinks", "budget" : 100, "spent" : 150 }
{ "_id" : 5, "category" : "travel", "budget" : 200, "spent" : 650 }
```