# check if one key is greater than another key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to compare one key value with another key value in mongodb. can any one help me with this query.

example:

```
{
"_id":"xxxxx",
"game":"xxx",
"score":100,
"hi-score":200
}
```

i want to check if score is greater than hi-score

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501337/mongodb-aggregation-framework-match-between-fields

Comment: you should use Aggrigation framework  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/cmp/#_S_cmp

Answer (score -1):

Try the below query using http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

```
db.collection.find( { $where: "this.score > this.hi-score" } );
```

Also, please read the warning section provided in the link.

PS: I have not tried this

Comment: -1: 1.) you could simply copy the warning that it's slow. 2.) this code doesn't work 3.) the hyphen requires special care, javascript reads it as an operator

Comment: @mnemosyn The link very clearly describes the warning so there is no need to copy, however if you think its needed then please feel free to update. Moreover the code is pasted to give an idea of how it could be achieved not the exact code. I am pretty sure the person who has put this question is capable enough to figure out simple changes he or she is supposed to do to make it work. Thanks anyway.